# Registry Access in ASP.NET Application running on Windows 7

Tags: .net, asp.net, iis-7, windows-7, registry

I've migrated an ASP.NET web application from Server 2003(x86) to a Windows 7(x64) machine.  The web application cannot find registry values that were stored under:

**SOFTWARE\SomeApplicationName\SubLocation\SubLocation2**

being accesed through the **Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey** api located in the Microsoft.Win32 namespace.

My question is: **Where do I need to place these values for the ASP.NET web app to access them from the Windows 7 registry?  The web application is hosted in IIS7**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I placed the registry setting in the same path under the 64bit registry on the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Please learn about registry under WOW64,

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896459

Regards,